# Is it possible to set up an alias on an Active Directory domain controller Linux server?

Tags: linux, active-directory, domain, directory

We have a Red Hat Enterprise based Linux distro that is the domain controller for a bunch of Win 10 clients. Some clients are not in the right AD domain (they are on a former domain that was used before the server crashed and was reconfigured before I came here.)
I can't change them to the right domain because I can't login with admin account.
Now, I'd like to set up an alias for the old domain so the clients can find and login on the server. So how do I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how domains work. They won't be able to login or otherwise work correctly with the new domain even if you were able to set up "alias".

Use tools, (e.g. `chntpw`) to change admin passwords in those computers, then join them correctly into the new domain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I contacted the support and they said the same. I thought I'd just reinstall them, but I'll look into this tool you mentioned. If it's simpler than a reinstall I might use it.

Comment: Please accept this reply as the answer because it's correct that you need to join the machines to the correct domain, whether or not you crack the admin passwords. Saves time for other people who think it hasn't been answered.